# Doubt in the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem. The Theorem claims the following

> Let $U\subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ be a simply connected domain. Then there exists an injective holomorphic map $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$.

The first step of the proof says that WLOG we can assume that $0\notin U$ and $1\in U$.

I cannot understand why this is true. Any idea?

Comment: Just hit $U$ with a linear map $\alpha z + \beta$ so that $1$ is in the image and $0$ is not.

Comment: If you're having trouble seeing the linear map, note you can bring any two distinct points to $0$ and $1$ by 1) translating the first to the origin. 2) rotating and dilating to place the second at $1.$